# Breaking template on {% load rango_template_tags %}

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I am half way through a tutorial useing the book Tango With Django trying desperately hard to take on as much information as i can about Django.

Now i am trying to set up a template that lists all the category's but i get an error

```
invalid syntax (rango_template_tags.py, line 8)
```

I have no idea why i am getting this line, absolutely none i have checked it with the book 5 + times but i cant find anything that looks out of place of wrong. Can anyone please tell me why i am getting this error.

**Base.html**

```
 {% load rango_template_tags %}
 <div> 
    {% block sidebar_block %} 
         {% get_category_list %}  
    {% endblock %}
 </div>
 # This file has more within it these are the new pieces of code that break the template system. If these are in it wont work.
```

**rango_template_tags**

```
 from django import template
 from rango.models import Category

 register = template.Library()

 @register.inclusion_tag('rango/cats.html')
 def get_category_list():
 return {'cats' Category.objects.all()}
```

**cats.html**

```
<ul>
  {% if cats %}
    {% for c in cats %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'show_category' c.slug %}">{{ c.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
      <li><strong> There ar eno categories presen. </strong></li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Comment: You have at least two errors on that line. Check again.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you go further into detail please?

Comment: You checked it with the book 5 + times, I wonder which book is that? Indent the `return` line and put a colon after dictionary key (`'cats'`).

Comment: Can you really not see the difference between the snippet [in the book](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/template_tags.html#using-template-tags) and the one you've posted here? As I say, there are two obvious errors.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you so much it was the colon, Such a stupid mistake! It was already indented in my text editor didn't copy it over correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielRoseman It was the colon, i have been using the pdf version of the book the link you provided make it easier thanks. Try not to have a dick-ish attitude all your life.

Answer (score 1):

> In python dictionary, each key is separated from its value by a colon (:)

Change your return statement from {'cats' Category.objects.all()} to {'cats': Category.objects.all()} and code within **function or block should be idented**.

```
 from django import template
 from rango.models import Category

 register = template.Library()

 @register.inclusion_tag('rango/cats.html')
 def get_category_list():
     return {'cats': Category.objects.all()}
```

Comment: Please offer some explanation to improve the quality of your answer. See here for help on [Writing a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).